# JOOQ - Is there any similar tool like SQL 2 jOOQ Parser?

Tags: jooq

Since JOOQ 3.6+, they no longer ship with SQL 2 jOOQ Parser. Search on the internet, I can't find the tool SQL 2 jOOQ Parser anywhere.

Just wonder is there any similar tool like SQL 2 jOOQ Parser so we can generate the JOOQ code from native sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a feature request for this:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6277

From the feature request:

> This was already implemented in the past by the https://github.com/sqlparser/sql2jooq third party module, but it suffered from several flaws:
>
> - It didn't produce very good jOOQ code
> - It worked only for MySQL and PostgreSQL
> - It depended on a third party parser (by Gudu Soft), which was proprietary and not under our control
> - It was hard to use

The product got zero (!) user feedback over quite some time, which is never a good sign.

Eventually, we'll re-iterate the idea, but it's *a lot* of work, and there are probably more interesting things that can be done first. The approach most people will choose when writing jOOQ queries is they:

- Choose a test driven approach where the feedback cycle is tight, such that executing a query to test if it's correct is done relatively easily
- Use views (seriously, use views! Why don't people use views more often?) for your very complex static SQL and query the views from jOOQ